# Uncaught exception 'Fuel\Core\PhpErrorException' ....system's timezone settings

Tags: php, timezone, fuelphp

I Using Php 5.3, while changing from UTC To EDT/-4.0/DST Timezone it give the following errors.
Please Help Me Out...Thanks.i will describe before and after timezone change errors...

BEFORE timezone CHANGE:

Fuel\Core\PhpErrorException [ Error ]:
date_default_timezone_get() [function.date-default-timezone-get]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead

```
COREPATH/classes/fuel.php @ line 161

156            date_default_timezone_set(static::$timezone);
157        }
158        catch (\Exception $e)
159        {
160            date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
161            throw new \PHPErrorException($e->getMessage());
162        }
163
164        static::$encoding = \Config::get('encoding', static::$encoding);
165        MBSTRING and mb_internal_encoding(static::$encoding);
<br />
```

AFTER TIME ZONE CHAGE TO 'EDT/-4.0/DST'

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception 'Fuel\Core\PhpErrorException' with message 'Unknown: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead' in Unknown:0
Stack trace:
#0 /home/files/website/bus/fuel/core/bootstrap.php(98): Fuel\Core\Error::error_handler(2, 'Unknown: It is ...', 'Unknown', 0)
#1 [internal function]: {closure}(2, 'Unknown: It is ...', 'Unknown', 0, Array)
#2 {main}

thrown in **Unknown** on line **0**

**Warning**:  file(Unknown) [function.file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **/home/files/website/bus/fuel/core/classes/debug.php** on line **325**

**Warning**:  array_unshift() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in **/home/files/website/bus/fuel/core/classes/debug.php** on line **326**

**Warning**:  array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in **/home/files/website/bus/fuel/core/classes/debug.php** on line **341**

Backtrace
COREPATH/bootstrap.php @ line 66

```
61            \Cli::error("Error: ".$e->getMessage()." in ".$e->getFile()." on ".$e->getLine());
62            \Cli::beep();
63            exit(1);
64        }
65    }
66    return \Error::shutdown_handler();
67});
68
69set_exception_handler(function (\Exception $e)
70{
71    // reset the autoloader
```

Comment: You need to use a *valid* timezone name. `EDT/-4.0/DST` is not one. https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Nope! Not working! i added america timezones America/Belize and more but not working.

Comment: Where did you add it? To `php.ini`? (That's where you need to do this.)